# Is a company required to supply sufficient car parking spots for its employees?

Tags: employment, netherlands, parking

Is a company required to supply sufficient car parking spaces for its employees?
There are not enough parking spaces at my office, causing some employees to park at the neighbour's lot, who have now started threatening to tow the cars away.

Is there anything an employee can do to force the company to arrange more parking spaces?

Carpooling or public transport is no option as I live in a very remote area.

Comment: Unless they've said explicitly that carparks are available as part of the employment contract, almost certain that they don't have to, and might be very limited in whether they can provide more.

Comment: It is also policy about limiting parking places per office building. They are trying to force people travel by public transport.

Comment: You are probably asking about car parking specifically (as opposed to e.g. bike parking), and you question seems to be about employees. I took the liberty of editing that into the question. If that's not what you intended, feel free to re-edit to clarify.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I advise you not to complain that "there are more employees than parking spaces".  They might find a creative way to bring the numbers into agreement.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no general law in the Netherlands (nor elsewhere in Europe, as far as I know) that would require an employer to provide employees with car parking spaces.

There are rules in some countries (or cities) about how many parking spaces must be built when a new building is built, or an existing building is converted (for example the [Stellplatzverordnung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellplatzverordnung) in Germany), but even that only requires a certain number of parking spaces, not a space for every employee.

In general, the rule is that getting to and from work is the employee's problem, so if you cannot park your car at work, you will have to find a different solution (park elsewhere and walk/bike the rest, public transport, car pooling).

---

Legal issues aside, most employers do want to help employees get to work safely and efficiently, so try talking to your employer. Maybe they can arrange something, such as car pooling, discounted tickets for public transport, showers at work for people who ride a bike or similar. However, usually you have no legal right to expect this.

---

Finally, there may also be tax issues if the employer organizes parking spaces for the employees: If the employers reimburses the employee's commuting cost (this would include paying for their parking), then *payment exceeding 19 cent per kilometer is taxable income for the employee* (source:  [Parkeren bij het werk straks betaald parkeren voor de baas?](https://www.salaris-informatie.nl/ingezonden-artikelen/parkeren-bij-het-werk-straks-betaald-parkeren-voor-de-baas)).
So if your employer rented additional parking space for you, depending on the cost for the employer, this might increase your tax burden.

For example, if you drive 10 km to work, the employer could reimburse a total of 20 x 0.19 cent x 215 days = 817 Euro per year. If the parking space cost 1,500 Euro per year (not uncommon), 683 Euro would count as taxable income.